# Use jpackage with WiX 4

Tags: java, jpackage

I am trying to package an application with `jpackage` for Windows. I am using `Java 19` and `WiX 4`.

```
Package Id      Version              Commands
---------------------------------------------
wix             4.0.0-preview.1      wix
```

```
java 19.0.1 2022-10-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)
```

According to the `Packaging Tool User's Guide`, the requirements for generating an installation package for windows are:

> WiX 3.0 or later is required.

However, when trying to generate a package I get an error:

```
[09:26:34.026] Can not find WiX tools (light.exe, candle.exe)
[09:26:34.026] Download WiX 3.0 or later from https://wixtoolset.org and add it to the PATH.
```

The very nature of the problem is clear. `jpackage` does not support `WiX 4`, although it is not written anywhere in plain text.

The solution is also clear, I install `WiX 3`. However, here comes the "problem". `WiX 3` requires an old version of .Net (3.5.1) or at least "Windows features .Net 3.5.1". However, this is what I want to avoid.

My question is, as of today, is there a way to directly use `WiX 4` with `jpackage`?

Comment: Are `light` and `candle` not included in `wix 4`? They have to be on the PATH I think for `jpackage` to find them.

Comment: @JornVernee, Yes, in `wix 4` the two tools, `light.exe` and `candle.exe` are replaced by a common one named `wix.exe`. The new `wix.exe` tool has an option to convert projects from `wix 3` to `wix 4` which gives a chance to manually migrate a package already generated by `jpakager` with `wix 3` (as long as its temp files are available). But I don't know if the effort is worth it. I find it easier to generate the app-image with `jpakager` (or if I use my launcher with `jlink`) and do the installer with `inno setup` (due to fewer dependencies).

Comment: Did you learn anything more about this? Is there an enhancement request to support Wix 4 (I couldn't find any)?

Comment: Just to add I have the identical problem. I am using jpackage version: 17.0.7 the version of jpackage that sipped with my GraalVM v17. Is jpackage that ships with  GraalVM v20, Wix 4 compatible?

Comment: I ran into this issue as well. I reluctantly downloaded .Net 3.5.1 and WiX 3. Managed to produce an installer but it wouldn’t run. I’m not gonna investigate further because it all seems like a suboptimal solution until WiX 4 is supported. To avoid ambiguity they should anyway change the requirements to something like “WiX (>3.0 && <4.0) is required”.

Comment: There's now an enhancement request to support WiX v4: [JDK-8319457](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8319457). We'll see if something comes of it.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround using `wix-3` (no need to mess with dotnet):

1. Download `wix311-binaries.zip` from [WiX Toolset v3 releases](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases)
2. Unpack the archive into `wix3` folder
3. Add the `wix3` folder to `PATH` environment variable
4. Restart your terminal for the PATH setting to take effect
5. Try `jpackage` again